# App crashes with a 'consider adding error boundaries to tree' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to get the status to change to shared if it's userA and if isshared is true. However, with the code I have below, the app crashes with a 'consider adding error boundaries to your tree', and with few changes, it returns same value despite isshared being true or false.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getLocalStorageStore } from "@/store/localStorage/utils";

const FileResults: React.FC<FileResultType> = props => {
  const { results, filename, status = "shared" } = props;

  const { email = "", isShared = false } = useSelector(getLocalStorageStore);
  const isUserA = email.toLowerCase().includes("usera");

  return (
    <>
      <tr className="file-result">
        <td>{results || "--"}</td>
        <td>{filename || "--"}</td>
        <td>{isUserA && isShared === true ? status : "private"}</td>
      </tr>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileResults;
```

Comment: Check if the email value is returned as null

Comment: can you share the full error message

Comment: Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behaviour. It returns a blank page.